# errors sonata.core.form.type.* after update sonata core

Tags: symfony, composer-php, package, sonata-admin, sonata

I have error after update to sonata core 3.13.4

URL: /admin/sonata/page/page/tree

ERROR:
The type name specified for the service "sonata.core.form.type.equal" does not match the actual name. Expected "Sonata\CoreBundle\Form\Type\EqualType", given "Sonata\Form\Type\EqualType"

Any ideas?

It is my installed packages

```
"symfony/symfony": "^3",
"symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3.10",
"symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0.2",
"symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",

"sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
"sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",

"twig/twig": "^1.34",
"doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
"doctrine/phpcr-odm": "^1.2",
"doctrine/phpcr-bundle": "^1.3",
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
"doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
"gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "^2.4",
"pixassociates/sortable-behavior-bundle": "^1.1",
"beberlei/DoctrineExtensions": "^1.0",

"symfony-cmf/routing-bundle": "^2.0",

"knplabs/knp-markdown-bundle": "^1.5",
"knplabs/doctrine-behaviors": "^1.1",
"knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "^2.6",

"sonata-project/core-bundle": "^3",
"sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^3",
"sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^3",
"sonata-project/media-bundle": "^3",
"sonata-project/classification-bundle": "^3",
"sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "^2",
"sonata-project/intl-bundle": "^2",
"sonata-project/notification-bundle": "^3",
"sonata-project/formatter-bundle": "^3",
"sonata-project/datagrid-bundle": "^2",
"sonata-project/seo-bundle": "^2",
"sonata-project/page-bundle": "^3",
"sonata-project/block-bundle": "^3",
"sonata-project/user-bundle": "4.1.1",
"sonata-project/translation-bundle": "^2",
"sonata-project/timeline-bundle": "^3",

"egeloen/ckeditor-bundle": "^5.0",
"tilleuls/ckeditor-sonata-media-bundle": "^1.0",
"friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^2.1",

"stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "^1.2",

"incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",

"jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal": "^1.2",

"nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "^2.13",

"simplethings/entity-audit-bundle": "^1.0",

"a2lix/i18n-doctrine-bundle": "@stable",
"a2lix/auto-form-bundle": "0.x@dev",
"a2lix/translation-form-bundle": "2.4.1",
"Migo2468/sonata-translation-bundle": "dev-master",

"cron/cron-bundle": "^1.2",
"knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle": "^1.25",
"league/oauth2-facebook": "^2.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

We did an unsuccessful split of the core bundle, we are trying to solve these issues. For now, the solution is to downgrade.

Could you please open an issue about this in the repo https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataCoreBundle.

Comment: Thanks for answer.

Comment: Can you tell me which version of sonata will be compatibile together? I had a other problems with earlier versions (e.g Twig and this problem https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataCoreBundle/issues/607)